# How To Use Hibernate 4 with WildFly 13

Tags: hibernate, wildfly, infinispan, wildfly-13

Is it possible to run applications using `hibernate-core-4.x` on `Wildfly 13`?

I'm pretty sure that hibernate 4 is **not** supported on WildFly13, however I have a requirement to do it anyways. Part of the reasoning for this is that the application is using some classes that are no longer present in hibernate 5 (`Mappings` for example), and it would be a huge effort to change them.

My preference is to just update the application, but I need to show "due diligence" (or whatever) to justify the effort.

The exceptions we are seeing have to do with getting hibernate 4 to play nice with infinispan 9, or maybe down grading infinispan to version "6.x" as well.

All my relevant experience up to know has been with Tomcat, so I'm needing some help on this by either getting it to work, or being able to show official documentation or statements saying hibernate 4 is not supported.

**Stacktrace**

2018-07-11 17:30:17,034 ERROR (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) [stderr]          at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parseElement(ParserRegistry.java:174)

2018-07-11 17:30:17,050 ERROR (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) [stderr]          at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:150)

2018-07-11 17:30:17,050 ERROR (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) [stderr]          at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:137)

2018-07-11 17:30:17,050 ERROR (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) [stderr]          at org.infinispan.configuration.parsing.ParserRegistry.parse(ParserRegistry.java:123)

2018-07-11 17:30:17,050 ERROR (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) [stderr]          at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.createCacheManager(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:415)

2018-07-11 17:30:17,050 ERROR (Thread-1 (ActiveMQ-client-global-threads)) [stderr]          at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.InfinispanRegionFactory.start(InfinispanRegionFactory.java:323)

Code in parser registry throwing the exception:

```
public void parseElement(XMLExtendedStreamReader reader, ConfigurationBuilderHolder holder) throws XMLStreamException {

    QName name = reader.getName();

    ParserRegistry.NamespaceParserPair parser = (ParserRegistry.NamespaceParserPair)this.parserMappings.get(name);
    if (parser == null)
    {
        String uri = name.getNamespaceURI();
        int lastColon = uri.lastIndexOf(':');
        String baseUri = uri.substring(0, lastColon + 1) + "*";
        parser = (ParserRegistry.NamespaceParserPair)this.parserMappings.get(new QName(baseUri, name.getLocalPart()));
        if ((parser == null) || (!isSupportedNamespaceVersion(parser.namespace, uri.substring(lastColon + 1)))) throw log.unsupportedConfiguration(name.getLocalPart(), name.getNamespaceURI());
    }
    Schema oldSchema = reader.getSchema();
    reader.setSchema(Schema.fromNamespaceURI(name.getNamespaceURI()));
    parser.parser.readElement(reader, holder);
    reader.setSchema(oldSchema);
}
```

Comment: You cannot get Hibernate 4 and Infinispan 9 working together. Infinispan 9.3 supports only Hibernate 5.1 and 5.3.

Comment: @TristanTarrant I kind of suspected that. Would it be possible to downgrade infinispan to a compatible version using the WildFly provisioning plugins for gradle|maven? I kind of get how the "features" can be configured, but I'm still unclear about how or whether downgrading would conflict with default versions.

Comment: Do you have to use Wildfly 13?  Wildfly 10, for example, uses Hibernate 4.x.

Comment: @stdundbar Yes. WildFly 13 contains a bug fix that I require, and that is not in any other version of WildFly/jBoss.

Comment: Time to upgrade to Hibernate 5.1/5.3 then?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in my project using jboss-deployment-structure.xml in my project with the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
<deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="4.3"/>
        </dependencies>
</deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

There also slot 4.1

I hope it helps.